# How can I access performance counters of garbage collector programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I have an app written in .Net Compact Framework 3.5 & C#, running on Windows Embedded Compact 7, I want to know how often and how much time GC is taking.

I have platform builder remote tools but I can't find anything which shows GC counters.

Is there a way to access them programmatically in C# or C++ etc ?

Is there any tool which can help me finding these counters ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a profiler that supports this?

Answer (score 1):

[Remote Performance Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa462522.aspx) (RPM) will show you GC counts live, so you can get those numbers from it.  Unfortunately there's no SDK or API for it.  [This blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevenpr/archive/2006/04/17/577636.aspx) is a little more in-depth on the tool.